# Assignment of initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, initializer-list, overload-resolution

The code below is a minimal example of my problem. I created a simple template class containing a fixed-size array, and overloaded the assignment operator to accept any class defining the methods `size()` and `begin()` (eg, `initializer_list`s). I don't understand why g++ is not able to resolve my call to this operator (I'm using gcc 4.6):

```
***.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
***.cpp:46:22: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘a = {42, -1.0e+0, 3.14158999999999988261834005243144929409027099609375e+0}’
***.cpp:46:22: note: candidates are:
***.cpp:23:8: note: template<class U> A<T, N>::self& A::operator=(const U&) [with U = U, T = double, unsigned int N = 3u, A<T, N>::self = A<double, 3u>]
***.cpp:8:7: note: A<double, 3u>& A<double, 3u>::operator=(const A<double, 3u>&)
***.cpp:8:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initialiser list>’ to ‘const A<double, 3u>&’
***.cpp:8:7: note: A<double, 3u>& A<double, 3u>::operator=(A<double, 3u>&&)
***.cpp:8:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initialiser list>’ to ‘A<double, 3u>&&’
```

The first candidate is listed correctly, but there is no error message associated. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename T, unsigned N>
class A
{
public:

    typedef A<T,N> self;

    // Default ctor
    A() {}

    // Copy ctor
    template <typename U>
    A( const U& other ) { operator=(other); }

    // Assignemnt
    template <typename U>
    self& operator= ( const U& other )
    {
        if ( other.size() == N )
            std::copy_n( other.begin(), N, m_data );
            return *this;
    }

    // Display contents
    void print() const
    {
        for ( unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i )
            std::cout << m_data[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    T m_data[N];
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    A<double,3> a;
    a = {42,-1.0,3.14159};
    a.print();
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be ambiguous, or what I did wrong?

---

Note: Ideally, I would even like to replace the first two lines of my main by a single one `A<double,3> a = {42,-1.0,3.14159};` but I'm not sure how, I currently get the following error:

```
***: In function ‘int main()’:
***:45:34: error: could not convert ‘{42, -1.0e+0, 3.14158999999999988261834005243144929409027099609375e+0}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initialiser list>’ to ‘A<double, 3u>’
```

Comment: If you read the [C++11 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info) it clearly states questions tagged [tag:C++11] should also be tagged [tag:C++].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `auto`, where a braced-init-list is deduced as an `initializer_list`, template argument deduction considers it to be a non-deduced context, unless there exists a corresponding parameter of type `initializer_list<T>`, in which case the `T` can be deduced.

From *§14.8.2.1/1 [temp.deduct.call]* (emphasis added)

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it `P`) with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below. If removing references and cv-qualifiers from `P` gives `std::initializer_list<P0>` for some `P0` and the argument is an initializer
>   list (8.5.4), then deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer list, taking `P0` as a function template parameter type and the initializer element as its argument. **Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context** (14.8.2.5).

Thus the argument to your `operator=` is not deduced to be an `initializer_list<double>`. For the code to work, you must define an `operator=` that takes an `initializer_list` argument.

```
template <typename U>
self& operator= ( const std::initializer_list<T>& other )
{
    if ( other.size() == N )
        std::copy_n( other.begin(), N, m_data );
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the explanation I was asking the others, my mistake is clear now. Thank you very much again :)

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I saw your comment below juan's answer where you said this is just an example you cooked up, but (without seeing your real implementation) this doesn't look like a very good idea to me either. If you have a class that encapsulates a fixed size array, your copy-constructor/assignment operator should probably only accept another instance containing the same sized array, rather than conditionally copying or throwing exceptions.

Comment: My "real" code issues an error message and doesn't copy (without exception) if the input container does not have the same size. Does that seem sound to you?

Answer (score 2):

A brace-enclosed initializer list does not necessarily have the type `std::initializer_list<T>`, so you need to specify that the assignment operator template expects an `std::initializer_list`:

```
  template <typename U>
  A& operator=(std::initializer_list<U> other )
  {
    if ( other.size() == N )
      std::copy_n( other.begin(), N, m_data );
    return *this;
  }
```

or

```
  A& operator=(std::initializer_list<double> other )
  {
    if ( other.size() == N )
      std::copy_n( other.begin(), N, m_data );
    return *this;
  }
```

I must say, an assignment operator that silently fails if the sizes don't match doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: Same than @ooga, I would be interested to know a little more than what I need to do in order for it to work, would you mind explaining what's happening? For you latter concern, this is a minimal example, my code does not fail silently in this case.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn I added something at the beginning of my answer. I think the number of cases when a brace enclosed initializer list maps to an `std::initializer_list` is limited. You have to tell the compiler what you want here.

Comment: Thanks :) I prefer the answer of @Praetorian, the standard explains exactly why this happens, although I'm not sure why they chose to handle it like this.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say it's this:

```
A<double,3> a;
a = {42,-1.0,3.14159};
```

You are initializing `a` with default constructor, and then trying to use initializer list on already initialized object - which complains about lacking of appropriate `operator=` overload. Instead try:

```
A<double,3> a = {42,-1.0,3.14159};
```

EDIT:

You also didn't defined required constructor:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
class A
{
public:
    A(std::initializer_list list) : m_data(list) {}

//...
}
```

Comment: `a = {42,-1.0,3.14159};` is not initializing my object a second time, I'm using the templated assignment operator. For your suggestion, please read the end of my post.

Comment: ... Please read my post in full before your next edit. There is a templated constructor defined, and I am not using this constructor in the first part.

Comment: No one is able to tell how your code works if you hide important details and then downvote for not knowing them.

Comment: Not a perfect source but here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list it works - it only require `T` to take initializer list as a valid consctructor argument and replacing `T x[y]` with some std collection `T`.